# Why am I getting "Task is not in your gulpfile" when creating a task with arguments?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have created a simple task that takes an argument:

```
gulp.task("js", () => {
    let stream = gulp
        .src("./src/**/*.js", { base: "./src/" })
        .pipe($.plumber())
        .pipe($.changed("temp"))
        .pipe(babel());

    // minify is min argument provided
    if (args.min == true) stream = stream.pipe($.uglify());

    // Update paths
    stream
        .pipe(
            $.preprocess({
                context: {
                    PATH: save.dest,
                    COMMIT: pkg.version
                }
            })
        )
        .pipe(gulp.dest("temp"));

    return stream;
});
```

I want to minify based on whether I'm pushing to QA or PROD:

`gulp.task("push-dev", ["js"], function() {})`

`gulp.task("push-prod", ["js --min"], function() {})`

But I get the error:

> [11:51:32] Task 'js --min' is not in your gulpfile

Is what I'm trying possible? I'm trying to avoid having to create a whole new task just to handle minification in different environments.

Answer (score 1):

Define your function separately from your task instead of directly in your `gulp.task`.

```
let jsFunc = (doMininfy) => {
  let stream = gulp
    .src("./src/**/*.js", { base: "./src/" })
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.changed("temp"))
    .pipe(babel());

  // assuming you meant the parameter to go here?
  if (doMininfy) stream = stream.pipe($.uglify());

  // Update paths
  stream
    .pipe(
        $.preprocess({
            context: {
                PATH: save.dest,
                COMMIT: pkg.version
            }
        })
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest("temp"));

  return stream;
});

gulp.task("js", () => jsFunc());
gulp.task("js-min", () => jsFunc(true));
gulp.task("push-dev", ["js"], function() {});
gulp.task("push-prod", ["js-min"], function() {});
```